# Get incoming ssh forwarded connection port number

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, sshd

I have a server who is forwarding connections to a set of other servers.

Here I forward all incomming connections on:

my.tunnel.com:33199 to my.server2.com:52222

And..

my.tunnel.com:33200 to my.server3.com:52222

.. until

my.tunnel.com:XXXXX to my.serverN.com:52222

I'm initiating this by the following command on each server, except the tunnel my.tunnel.com:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root -i /etc/ssh/id_rsa -R *:33199:127.0.0.1:22 -p 443 my.tunnel.com 0 33199

...

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l root -i /etc/ssh/id_rsa -R *:XXXXX:127.0.0.1:22 -p 443 my.tunnel.com 0 XXXXX
```

Well, this works fine!

But!

At the point of the launching of each of these commands I'd like to check on my.tunnel.com that my.server2.com wants my.tunnel.com to forward exactly from port 33199, but not another port! So at this point I'd like to get this port number.

Please let me know if the problem is still not enough clearly exposed.

Thanks!

Comment: It is still not clear what you are asking, what port you mean. You should include some example.

Comment: @Tomas, I'have updated the question with an example

Comment: OK, now its more clear. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### To get the forwarded port

There is no such information in the environmental variables, so you must pass it yourself:

```
ssh -R 33199:127.0.0.1:22 my.tunnel.com "export MY_FWD_PORT=33199; my_command"
```

(my_command is the script you want to run on the server). More information about passing variables - https://superuser.com/q/163167/93604

#### To get the source port

Look at the environment variable `SSH_CONNECTION` in [man ssh(1)](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/ssh.1.php). Its meaning is:

```
source_ip source_port dest_ip dest_port
```

You probably want `source_port`, so just get the second part of it:

```
echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

or

```
echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d" " -f 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's too bad that this information in not available in the env variables. I fact I don't trust too much these servers, so it would be cool to be able to do this chack on the tunnel side. Thanks for the export tips !